# Is function is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ then it is uniformly continuous on subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, continuity, uniform-continuity

We know that, the function $f: \mathbb{R}→ \mathbb{R}$ such that  $f(x) = x$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Now, my **Question** is,  if we define the function $g:\mathbb{Q} →\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = x$ for all $x ∈ Q$ then is function $g$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{Q}$?

**My attempt**:
 as we know, continuity is domain based property. So to check continuity of $g$, we must consider the point of domain first!!. Now let $q ∈\mathbb{Q}$ then as we know, rationals are dense in $\mathbb{R}$ so, $q$ must be limit point of domain and not an isolated point of domain. So $g$ is continuous at $q$ if and only if, $$\lim_{x\to q} g(x) = g(q)$$
But is $$\lim_{x\to q+} g(x)=\lim_{x\to q-} g(x)$$? (I stuck here)

As between two rationals there is an irrational number and function is not defined their. So is left hand limit and right hand limit of $g$ as $x$ tends to $q$ are equal? Is $g$ is continuous at $q$ ? and what about uniform continuity? Please help me.

Comment: Start with the definition of uniform continuity, please.

Comment: Sir, to be uniform continuous function must be continuous there! So is $g$ is continuous on $\mathbb{Q}$ ?

Comment: Start with the definition of *uniform* continuity, please.

Comment: Please anyone help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have something like for all $x,y\in{\bf{R}}$, if $|x-y|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$.

Then, of course, for all $x,y\in S$, if $|x-y|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$, (or put it in this way: $|g(x)-g(y)|<\epsilon$.)

Here $S$ is any subset of ${\bf{R}}$.

Comment: But here $g$ is not $f$. $g$ is not defined on $\mathbb{Q^c}$. So how left hand limit of $g$ is equal to right and limit of $g$ (at $q$)

Comment: You see, actually you can replace the $f$ by $g$, do you know what I mean?

Comment: No. How we can? $g$ is restriction of $f$ to $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: Okay, like this: For $x\in S$, $f(x)=g(x)$.

Comment: Yes. But $f$ will be uniformly continuous. But how will be $g$ then? Since domain of $g$ is not connected set, whereas domain of $f$ is connected set.

Comment: There is no connectedness in issue for uniform continuity. As long as the expression like, for all $x,y\in\text{Domain of the function}$, if $|x-y|<\delta$, then...

Comment: Still I have confusion in "continuity" of $g$. Please could you help me in continuity of $g$ first?

Comment: Sir, For continuity left and limit must be equal to right hand limit and which is equal to value of function at that point. Is $g$ satisfies this?

Comment: Okay, like this: $\lim_{x\rightarrow a,x\in S}g(x)=g(a)$, which means, the running variable $x$ to $a$ must be lying in $S$.

Comment: So is this possible (your above comment). Since between two rational there are irrationals, so ""how"" lim g(x) as x→ a equal to g(a)?

Comment: Skip the irrational numbers, the running variable is just in rational, this is alright.

Comment: Ohhh finally got it. Is we are skipping irrationals because function is Not defined their? That's is domain of $g$ is just $\mathbb{Q}$. Is that's the reason we are skipping irrationals?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: Finally thank you so much sir. For your help.